# How to set QT_SCALE_FACTOR for Okular?

Tags: environment-variables, qt, okular

Okular's UI elements are too big. After some looking I found that `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` was set to 2 because my laptop's screen is 4K while my external monitor's is not. Even when my laptop's screen is off and the only display is my monitor, the `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` is still 2! What is the point in having a variable if it is not going to be set according to the current display... sigh.

Anyways, I noticed that if I run `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1 okular`, this brings up Okular with the right UI scale so I thought hey, let's just set the environment variable and be done with it. I put `export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1` in my `~/.bashrc`. Now `printenv | grep QT_SCALE` shows the variable set to 1 but here is the catch. Whenever I open a document by double clicking it or just Okular from the start menu, it is still over-scaled. Though, if I run `okular` in the terminal, it pops up with the correct scaling. Could someone help me set `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1` properly or better yet have be set according to the current display?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an executable file:

```
~/.local/bin/okular
```

with the following content:

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.2 /usr/bin/okular "$@"
```

Adjust the scale factor to your needs.